# WCF ConcurrencyMode.Multiple Connection best practices and Caching

Tags: .net, wcf, performance, multithreading, caching

I've got a WCF service with the following settings:

- NetNamedPipeBinding
- ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
- InstanceContextMode.Single

Now I've got a client that accesses to this WCF service in a multi-threaded fashion.

As far as I understand I have to open a new connection to the service for each thread to avoid threads to block each others.

- In this case how expensive is the `Open()` call (*service is in the same computer*)?
- Shall I cache/pool the my client class? (*derived from `ClientBase`*) or does WCF provides a transparent pool for connections similar to SQLConnection Pooling?

Comment: For such a scenario, NetNamedPipe on-machine communication, I don't see the added complexity of ConcurrencyMode.Multiple as a benefit. This just makes your service code that much more complex and error-prone.... I don't know if that's worth the trouble and possible maintenance hassle, compared to a few nanoseconds saved in client proxy creation.....

Comment: Without multiple it wouldn't work as multithreaded, that means multihtreading in the client would be pointless since it'll wait for each other. And it's not a milisecond call it takes seconds. Or am I missing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF unfortunately does not pool client connections. I've found that Open() is relatively slow and have built my own pooling mechanisms keeping a handful of persistent connections open between the client and server.

One common gotcha though regarding this is that if even something as simple as a time-out occurs between the client and server (or any sort of CommunicationException is thrown), the client instance enters a Faulted state and becomes unusuable. At which time you must destroy and replace it w/ a new instance.

Comment: aghh! that's pretty rubbish. I actually already built a caching system but I just don't like the idea of extra complexity. Thanks for the clarification +1.

Comment: I doubt the Open() call is slow in a "on-machine-only" call scenario with the NetNamedPipe binding. Yes, it might be slow using wsHttpBinding (the default) which has lots of WS-* feature overhead - but named pipes are very efficient, and on-machine only, next to no security - that should be no problem at all.

Comment: Even w/ NetNamedPipe, there's more overhead than I could stomach. Give it a whirl, seriously. On my lappy I saw the instantion time range from 150ms to 350ms. I ended up putting a pub/sub in front of a dispatcher w/ a pool of clients and saw pretty spectacular performance.

Answer (score 1):

James Alexander's answer is spot on (you have to pool connections yourself), but I figured I'd post [a link to a blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/04/21/wcf-client-performance.aspx) that discusses an implementation that adds connection pooling on top of ClientBase. [Here's the follow up post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/05/07/wcf-client-channel-pool-improved-client-performance.aspx) where he goes into details and provides a link to download the code.

Comment: good stuff, especially benchmarking. How about some code ? :) I already added some caching but your implementation looks neat, it would be nice to take a sneak peek :)

Comment: The blog post is actually not mine (don't want to steal credit!). I just know about it because I've researched this subject before. I should have given you the other link to his post where he actually gives more details and code. I will edit my entry.

Comment: ops! I see I thought that was your blog, anyway definitely good link to prove the point.