# Does WCF Service use multiple threads to process incoming requests?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, threadpool

How can I ensure that a WCF service uses threads from a ThreadPool to process incoming messages?

**At the moment simple method invocation like 'return null;' takes about 45 seconds while another requests are processing**

Here is how I have annotated my service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public partial class MyService : IMyService {
...
}
```

But when I'm watching the process in task manager it seems to be using a constant number of threads. Even under load.

---

```
public ActionResult SelectDatabase(string param)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            {
            try
            {
                MyServicece svc = new MyService();
                Database[] dbsArray = svc.GetDatabases(param);
                if (depsArray != null)
                    ViewData["depsArray"] = depsArray;

                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                // log here                
                return ActionUnavailable();
            }
        }
```

Here is my service behavior:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>

  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
    <bindings>      
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding sendTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None">           
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CrossDomainServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"   maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="MyService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AService.IAServ"  isSystemEndpoint="false" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService.MyServiceAdmin">
        <endpoint address="MyServiceAdmin" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyServiceAdmin"  isSystemEndpoint="false" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

---

Here is how I create service instance:

```
ServiceHost myserviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}/", _bindAddress)));
            myserviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(myserviceHost.BaseAddresses[0]);
```

Comment: InstanceContextMode = SIngle means: you have a **singleton** - just a single service instance. Not very scalable! ConcurrencyMode = Multiple means, that singleton can service multiple service requests at once - but it also means, your service implementation code **must** be 100% thread-safe - not an easy task! I would recommend using `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` and `ConcurrencyMode.Single` - that way, each incoming WCF request gets his own instance of a service class to handle the request. The WCF runtime can handle multiple concurrent requests, your code is easy to write.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609703/wcf-concurrencymode-multiple-connection-best-practices-and-caching

Comment: Sometimes InstanceContextMode = Single is ok - for example when the API is stateless and just forwards the call. No need to have more than one instance of the service ever created. For example method calls that return stuff like queue lengths or submit data to a processing queue... And writing 100% thread safe code is standard behavior for some of us - not everyone is a script kiddie.

Comment: @marc_s Please see my udpated question.

Answer (score 7):

InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode are separate concepts but which have a level of interplay - [I blogged about this](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,1efac821-2b89-47bb-9d27-48f0d6347914.aspx) in some depth a while back

WCF calls are processed on IO threadpool threads. Assuming you haven't done something like `ConcurrencyMode.Single`, `InstanceContextMode.Single` which will serialize every call into the service the threadpool manager will try to balance the number of threads to the rate of work.

If the number of concurrent requests can be serviced by 5 threads then that's how many it will use. You may be seeing that the threadpool can keep up with the rate of work with the number of threads you can see. You can quite happily use more threads than cores with effect because, as long as the threads are not purely CPU bound, the OS can gain throughput by switching threads onto the CPU when the previously running thread starts IO. If the CPU is completely max'd out then the heuristics of the threadpool manager will make it reticent to add more threads into the thread pool

However, there are another couple of potential issues:

1. Session based bindings can block on the client side while there are multiple concurrent outbound requests through the same proxy. You don;t say how you are generating the multiple requests so this may be an issue;
2. You may also be seeing throttling kicking in as, prior to .NET 4 the default max number of concurrent requests was 16 and default number of concurrent sessions was 10. These values have been raised in .NET 4 but you don't say which version of .NET you are using

Comment: I'm on .NET4. On ASP .NET website I'm creating new proxy every time I should request something from service. It seems like we are going on right way and this may be issue.

Comment: are you calling close on the proxy?

Comment: That's your problem - you have reached saturation point on the MaxConcurrentSessions throttle. Each request is having to wait for a previous session to timeout. Close or reuse the proxy and you should see your throughput increase - I blogged about sessions here http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,af6e6325-2e30-42e3-acb9-57e1363fa51e.aspx

Comment: I have `maxConcurrentCalls = "100"` in my config. Do you really think I'm reaching 100 concurrent calls?

Comment: No - as I said in my comment - you are hitting the session throttle. When you create a new proxy and use it it establishes a session. Unless you close the proxy the session will stay active for 20 minutes by default. As you use the site without closing the proxies eventually you hit the session throttle of 100 x number of cores (the default on .NET 4). New calls only some in as sessions time out

Comment: I rewrited my code to create one global application wide proxy and then just use it in all other controllers methods with pre-checking and recreating it if it's needed. Is it right path we should go?

Comment: For simplicity I'd be tempted to just keep the code as you have it but close the proxy once you've finished with it in each request and only change it if you are seeing that cause performance issues (proxy creation and teardown isn't free). I've sometimes seen proxies block on the client side when using multiple threads and a single proxy with NetTcpBinding - although I forget the underlying cause at the moment